# Trouble on proving a lemma - Complex Power Series

Tags: complex-numbers, power-series

I'm having some difficulties on proving the following lemma:

"If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions which converges uniformly to $0$ on a set $G$ and $z_n$ is any sequence in $G$ then the sequence $f_n$($z_n$) converges to $0$."

Any help on understanding this would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far :)

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

$$f_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{uniformly on}\;\;G\iff \forall\,\epsilon>0\;\;\exists\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.$$

$$n>N_\epsilon\implies |f_n(x)|<\epsilon\;\;\;\underline{\forall\,x\in G}$$

The important part here is that the above is true **for any** $\;x\in G\;$ ...can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The assumption means $\sup_{z \in G} |f_n(z)| \to_n 0$. The claim follows because $|f_n(z_n)| \leq \sup_{z \in G} |f_n(z)|$ for all $n$.